# How to Position inside a Stack widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-positioned, flutter-stacked

I have this `Stack` widget and a `Positioned` widget inside it. But the position of it doesn't change according to the properties of `Positioned`.

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Graphs'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          const Text(
            'test text',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                color: Colors.lightBlue),
          ),
          TextField(
            onChanged: (input) {
              setState(() {
                inEquation = input;
              });
            },
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              labelText: 'Enter equation',
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(      //the positioned widget I wanna position
            bottom : 50,
            right: 30,
            child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  toggled = !toggled;
                });
              },
            child: const Text('Enter'),),
          )],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I feel like it's getting positioned into the bigger widget in the `children` list of the `Stack`.

Comment: I'm running your exact code with the widget being built in a `StatefulWidget`, and the `MaterialButton` in `Positioned` is changing position accordingly to the `bottom` and `right` properties. 

Is there more context or a specific issue with the positioning?

Comment: @raw-chicken try changing the `bottom` property of the `MaterialButton` into something like 50... It won't show.
Thank you for your time

Comment: When the `bottom` property is 50, it's positioned out of the stack widget. Where are you trying to place the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occuring because Stack widget does not have any constraints. Due to no constraints, the Positioned() widget TextButton() is not visible.

To solve this wrap your Stack widget with constraints by using SizedBox() or Container() widget and set its height property.

```
body: SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            const Text(
              'test text',
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  color: Colors.lightBlue),
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (input) {
                setState(() {
                  inEquation = input;
                });
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Enter equation',
              ),
            ),
            Positioned(
              //the positioned widget I wanna position
              bottom: 50,
              right: 30,
              child: MaterialButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    toggled = !toggled;
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Enter'),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

[image]